# Is there an Intent in Android to open a small contact card?

Tags: android

The [ACTION_VIEW Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW) opens a full screen contact card Activity for a contact URI data.

Is there an intent (or perhaps an EXTRA flag) that can open the more compact version of this Activity? (Same as the one used by the native Contacts widget)

**EDIT:**
I've attached a screenshot of the compact contact card I want to show. Notice that it doesn't take up the full screen. It's the same one triggered from the Contact widget, the Messages app and the Talk app.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the Quick Contact Badge?

http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/display-contact-badge.html

**EDIT:**

If not looking to use the Badge pattern, you can invoke the QuickContact dialog manually:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.QuickContact.html

Comment: I don't think so, but I might be. I've edited the question and attached an example.

Comment: @TomerWeller Updated answer for more clarity.